# Javascript strange behavior on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I noticed a strange behavior of IE (any version : 7, 8 or even 9) when executing JavaScript : 
Drag and drop don't work, but when I press F12 button twice it work perfectly (F12 developer tools)

On Chrome, all code work in perfection, but in IE I should press F12 twice to let code run perfectly.

Can anyone explain what is this bug?

Comment: `Drag and drop don't work` can you share your code plz ?

Comment: The problem is not related to the code itself. I think I resolved the problem : `console.log();` I'm using developer tools in the function calls, i'll deactivate all these calls and I test again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess its because you are using console.log in your code

console.log is available after you open Developer Tools in IE. 
Use a try catch;

```
try{
    console.log('log')
}
catch(err){
}
```

Comment: Yeah like i said, what should happen if i comment it? now that i commented it nothing work anymore, i'll try to surround it with try/catch.